# ReWrite Rule Questions in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is working for changing my crappy urls to SEO friendly URLs:

```
^([0-9]+)/[a-z-]+/?$ /details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

except...  if there's a number in my title, it doesn't work.  How might I fix this.. or is there enough information given here to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you're using to match the title, `[a-z-]+`, only matches against lower case letters and a "-", so no numbers. To match numbers, you need a `0-9` in the brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9-]+/?$ /details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 good solution. I would add the `NC` flag just in case `[NC,L]